# my heroku aplication crashes (error H10) and I did not find a solution

Tags: python, heroku, server, terminal, plotly-dash

I'm trying to upload my dash plotly app to a heroku server but got a H10 error and haven't really found a solution that works.
I already get to the point that I can do a `git push heroku master` command without any problem but when I go to the page it just gives me an application error.

I tried to find the problem in the logs but I only see that it's the error H10. Tried to restart my heroku and dynos but nothing worked sadly.

Here are my logs:

```
(venv) C:\Users\bo112\PycharmProjects\ree-solution>heroku logs
2021-12-31T00:52:23.140568+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-31T00:52:23.140573+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2021-12-31T00:52:23.140830+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.140834+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141024+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141024+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141182+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141192+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 528, in reap_workers
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141402+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141457+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141460+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141460+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141460+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141462+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141568+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141576+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141667+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141677+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141813+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141822+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141934+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.141948+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142086+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142100+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142276+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142289+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142457+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142599+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142611+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 528, in reap_workers
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142796+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)
2021-12-31T00:52:23.142864+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2021-12-31T00:52:23.352627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-31T00:52:23.407605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-12-31T00:52:25.170212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ree-simulation.herokuapp.com request_id=a9827ad9-c637-4599-9604-f821903cecb4
 fwd="92.192.243.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-31T00:52:47.080234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-31T00:52:55.147630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dash_gui:app`
2021-12-31T00:52:56.454586+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:52:56 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-31T00:52:56.455065+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:52:56 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:11062 (4)
2021-12-31T00:52:56.455111+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:52:56 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-12-31T00:52:56.458059+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:52:56 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-12-31T00:52:56.520129+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:52:56 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-12-31T00:52:57.092025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T00:53:00.333410+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user maximilian.boje@gmail.com
2021-12-31T00:53:03.091954+00:00 app[web.1]: Application object must be callable.
2021-12-31T00:53:03.092120+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:53:03 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-12-31T00:53:03.108096+00:00 app[web.1]: Application object must be callable.
2021-12-31T00:53:03.108339+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:53:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-12-31T00:53:03.248123+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:53:03 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-31T00:53:03.343663+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:53:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-31T00:53:03.343825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 00:53:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2021-12-31T00:53:03.477047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2021-12-31T00:53:03.578509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-12-31T00:53:08.744551+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: Awaiting client
2021-12-31T00:53:08.760569+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-12-31T00:53:08.785616+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T00:53:12.285027+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-31T00:53:12.355417+00:00 heroku[run.8701]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-31T00:55:29.295119+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate` by user maximilian.boje@gmail.com
2021-12-31T00:55:36.923269+00:00 heroku[run.3897]: Awaiting client
2021-12-31T00:55:36.946046+00:00 heroku[run.3897]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2021-12-31T00:55:37.023226+00:00 heroku[run.3897]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T00:55:40.540428+00:00 heroku[run.3897]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-31T00:55:40.637392+00:00 heroku[run.3897]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-31T00:55:57.659124+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user maximilian.boje@gmail.com
2021-12-31T00:56:05.525586+00:00 heroku[run.4878]: Awaiting client
2021-12-31T00:56:05.549996+00:00 heroku[run.4878]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-12-31T00:56:05.550949+00:00 heroku[run.4878]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T00:56:09.099181+00:00 heroku[run.4878]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-31T00:56:09.387954+00:00 heroku[run.4878]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-31T00:56:48.759854+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `/app/bin/rails console` by user maximilian.boje@gmail.com
2021-12-31T00:56:56.494013+00:00 heroku[run.1635]: Awaiting client
2021-12-31T00:56:56.509737+00:00 heroku[run.1635]: Starting process with command `/app/bin/rails console`
2021-12-31T00:56:56.622717+00:00 heroku[run.1635]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T00:56:59.954161+00:00 heroku[run.1635]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-31T00:57:00.000643+00:00 heroku[run.1635]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-31T00:57:45.194060+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `console` by user maximilian.boje@gmail.com
2021-12-31T00:57:53.552210+00:00 heroku[run.3378]: Awaiting client
2021-12-31T00:57:53.568565+00:00 heroku[run.3378]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T00:57:53.570695+00:00 heroku[run.3378]: Starting process with command `console`
2021-12-31T00:57:57.075242+00:00 heroku[run.3378]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-31T00:57:57.126579+00:00 heroku[run.3378]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-31T01:26:06.329546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-31T01:26:15.167901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn dash_gui:app`
2021-12-31T01:26:16.444945+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-12-31T01:26:16.445355+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29350 (4)
2021-12-31T01:26:16.445397+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:16 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-12-31T01:26:16.448547+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:16 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-12-31T01:26:16.497420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-31T01:26:16.499670+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:16 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-12-31T01:26:22.475694+00:00 app[web.1]: Application object must be callable.
2021-12-31T01:26:22.475887+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-12-31T01:26:22.478327+00:00 app[web.1]: Application object must be callable.
2021-12-31T01:26:22.478470+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-12-31T01:26:23.125189+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:23 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-31T01:26:23.219621+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-31T01:26:23.219651+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-31 01:26:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2021-12-31T01:26:23.371891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2021-12-31T01:26:23.488200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I tried `heroku run rails console` and `heroku run rake db:migrate` but it didn't find the 'rail' or 'rake' command. If you had the same issue or know what's wrong, please let me know...

Comment: You need to get more of the logs, especially the parts _before_ the "*gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>*" part. [An H10 means your app crashed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed), which seemed to happen immediately on startup. You need to find the Traceback that (hopefully) shows which lines _on your app_ failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i am dumb.
my first procfile was good but then i made a new project since i had other problems earlier and recreated all the files. when i did that i accidentally had 'dash_gui:app' instead of 'dash_gui:server'....

love to see that i sat on that problem for like 4 hours because of this dumb mistake ._.